# Как сделать так, чтобы сайт на мобильном браузере выглядел так, как сайт после масштабирования в 300%?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я сделал сайт, который отрегулировал так, что при масштабировании в браузере на компе он выглядит достойно, как хорошая адаптация к мобильному устройству. При открытии сайта с телефона, сайт слишком мелкий, будто с компа открыли страницу в стандартном размере, и поместили на экран смартфона.
Как бы сделать так, чтобы  сайт на мобильном браузере выглядел так, как сайт после масштабирования в 300%(при таком увеличении он выглядит подходящим для экрана смартфона) ?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  добавь в `head`

Comment: Вообще в целом сразу лучше продумать сайт, до того как начинаешь его верстать. Адаптивность это вроде уже как норма.

Comment: Это мой первый сайт, который я делаю с css, и второй вообще. Потому речи о *сразу продумать сайт* не особо было))

Comment: @Air Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Тебе не меня надо благодарить, а @VladSpirin, его коммент важнее вернее, чем мой. Надо сразу учиться верстать правильно...